# How do I parse a specific cookie value?

Tags: python

So let's say that I need to have a CSRF Token to do a POST request to access an api and it requires a token to go through with the success, and the token is in the cookie, looks like this:

```
{'csrf_token': 'knjklfjg9g5yhbogbn98433y'}
```

How would I get just knjklfjg9g5yhbogbn98433y instead of the whole cookie?

Comment: How are you getting the cookie itself? Is it a string? Or is it a dict?

Comment: @rdas its a string

Comment: Is it a json string? Or does it look like what you have posted? (note JSON requires double-quotes)

Comment: @rdas it looks like what i posted

Comment: That's strange. You can try turning it into a dict with `eval(s)` but wouldn't recommend it. The cookie should be stored in a proper serilization format

Comment: That is a python dict.  Get the cookie value with `foo['csrf_token']`, where `foo` is whatever name you assigned to that dictionary.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python access JSON" or "Python access dict", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn a JSON string into a Python dictionary by using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

```py
import json
cookieStr = '{"csrf_token": "knjklfjg9g5yhbogbn98433y"}'
cookieDict = json.loads(cookieStr)
tokenValue = cookieDict["csrf_token"]
```